# mongoose, bulk create ensuring no duplication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I go about ensuring that when I do a bulk create operation that no duplicates are added.

I have an array of data, some of the documents data is unique, some is not. But this operation may be called multiple times and try to create duplicate data. Is there an option I can pass to ensure that data is not duplicated?

```
Main = mongoose.model('main', {
    id: String, // not '_id', this is separate
    name: String,
    data: {...}
});

Main.create([{},{},{}], (err, data) => {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Did you check mongodb's [bulk upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/)?